# Azure app service and authentication validate response time

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

To secure the request from the service developed in my application, I use a token from Azure AD and validate this token by a key confirmed by the Json from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys

In my local environment, it works fine, the time of response is less than 1s. But in Azure App Service, the same code takes around 15s just to get the Json from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys. I don't understand why we have this poor performance. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

To figure out which thread is causing performance issue , you can take a memory dumps and see thread by thread details.

Instruction for capturing Memory dump : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2017/05/04/azure-app-service-manually-collect-memory-dumps/